# Bluetooth works only for a very small range

Tags: bluetooth, manjaro, realtek

I have a `rtl8723be` chip in my laptop with Manjaro distro. The bluetooth didn't used to work but I have got it working by removing the `tlp` package which is responsible for runtime power management.

But I have an issue where the bluetooth works only upto a feet or two from the laptop. Beyond that, the connection weakens and completely dsconnects at about 6-7 feets.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If wifi is completely disabled, does your bluetooth range improve?

Comment: @robbat2 What do you mean by "completely disabled"? I tried removing the wifi module using modprobe, but that doesn't help. Neither does turning off wifi.

Comment: The driver for wifi requires use of an option `ant_sel` to select one antenna from the laptop(as there is only one antenna). I tried changing and removing that option. But it doesn't affect bluetooth at all.

Comment: Ok, so it's not likely to be interference. Can you be more specific about the laptop hardware, bluetooth client hardware (if it's a BLE device, 6ft is the expected range), and if this problem occurs on other OS (esp Windows)?

It's possible that bluetooth can share the wifi antenna in some systems, as they are both the same 2.4Ghz band.

Comment: @robbat2 I am trying to connect it with android devices, so it's not BLE. In windows, the bluetooth worked easily for 15-20 feet (maybe more). The laptop is [HP ac179tx](https://support.hp.com/my-en/document/c04919819). What else information can I provide?

Comment: That Windows gets better results IS very surprising, and suggests that the Windows driver is doing something differently than the Linux driver. Your best bet is to look for bluetooth hardware config knobs in Windows, and get Linux to match.

Comment: TLP is a set of power management utilities, so it is something you want to have installed! Also, looking [here](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-developer-documentation.html#files) which shows there are some scripts you can try (e.g. tlp-rf and tlp-rf-func) to see if you can get it to power up correctly. It almost sounds as though you now have it powering up into a default state, but it is not fully powered (maybe because TLP is now missing!).

Comment: @tniles09 How can I increase the power then? The problem with tlp is that with it installed, bluetooth won't even power up. Either I have to remove it or block the device in tlp. Could there be another solution?

Comment: @robbat2 How do I do that? I could get info from windows but I'm not sure how I can set that in Linux

Comment: I don't have that chip anywhere to test, but further googling on it suggests that loading the module w/ `fwlps=0 ips=0` might help. There's also a fork of the official driver that turned up, so really YMMV.

Comment: @RegisteredUser I am specifically wondering if you tried using any of the utilities TLP has (e.g. tlp-rf and tlp-rf-func). It is clear you had TLP installed, then uninstalled it, and saw different results. It is not clear if you tried manually tweaking things via TLP, which may get you somewhere. I have not used TLP tools at all.

Comment: @tniles09 I am unable to use those utilities. They don't have any help information neither could I locate any documentation. I installed tlp and tlp-rdw, but I can't figure how to use them, beyond blocking the device in tlp, which is the only way I have found to get bluetooth working. **The problem is indeed with transmit power level, as blueman shows it to be 50%, recieved signal strength to be 32%, and link quality to be 10%**